# hover effect is not working when background color is changed. Default color is transparent

Tags: html, css

```
<button class="button-main slide">Slide Left</button>

.button-main{
  color: black; 
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  padding: 8px 10px; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 16px 'Bitter', sans- serif; 
  line-height: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none; 
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.button-main :before,
.button-main :after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #259f6c; 
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3D(0,-100%,0); 
  transition: all .5s;
}

.button-main :before {
  background: #fafcd6; 
  z-index: -2;
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
}

.button-main :hover {
    color: white;
}

.button-main :hover: after {
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.slide :after {
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3D(-101%,0,0);
}

.slide :hover :after {
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

The hover slide effect on the button is not working when the background color of the button is changed to non-transparent color. The default color of the button in button-main is transparent. What needs to be changed so that when I changed the button background to red, for example, the slide hover effect will work?

Comment: Could you please help me re-write my codes here: https://codepen.io/amex-riexav/pen/XWMGMgJ

Comment: It's because when you the `background-color: transparent;` then you can see the after pseudo element cause it's behind the button but when u change the `background-color` to a solid color it's actually still working behind the button although you can't see it.

Comment: can you help me rewrite the codes please?

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced all the after elements with before because we need it to display before the element not after.
And I have also removed the before elements.

```html
<button class="button-main slide">Slide Left</button>
<style type="text/css">

.button-main{
 color: black; 
 outline: none;
 background: red;
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #eee;
 letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
 padding: 8px 10px; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font: bold 16px 'Bitter', sans- serif; 
   line-height: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none; 
 overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.button-main:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
   top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #259f6c; 
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3D(0,-100%,0); 
  transition: all .5s;
}
   
.button-main:hover{
    color: white;
}

.button-main:hover:before{
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
  transition: all .5s;
}

/* //// Slide Left  //// */

.slide:before{
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3D(-101%,0,0);
}

</style>
```